# How to pass active id to a popup in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: python, openerp-7

I am trying to pass the active id to a popup window so that in my function I can access the actual state of the caller object.

For that, I'm doing the following. In XML view:

```
<page string="Opinions">
    <field name="opinion_ids" context="{'generic_request_id': active_id}" >
        <tree delete="false"> 
            <field name="request_state" />
            <field name="opinion_request_date" />
            <field name="requestor" />
        (...)
```

In python I have:

```
_defaults={
    'state': 'requested',
    'opinion_request_date': lambda *a: datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    'request_state': lambda self, cr, uid, context: self._get_request_state(cr, uid, context=context), #store the state of the request when opinion was asked
    (...)
}
(...)
def _get_request_state(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    ids = context.get('generic_request_id', False)
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()        
    return self.pool.get('generic.request').browse(cr, uid, ids, context).state
```

In pdb I realize that "ids" is False because there is no generic_request_id variable in context...

```
(Pdb) p ids
False

(Pdb) p context
{'lang': 'en_US', 'no_store_function': True, 'tz': False, 'uid': 1}
```

Anyone knows a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I end up using a workflow function, no need to context.
Since my `opinions`object has a `many2one` connection with my `requests` object, the `id` of the parent request is stored in the `generic_request_id` field.

Upon creation, my workflow is triggered and I update the fields `state` with its new value and `request_state` with the value stored in my calling object.

```
def request_opinion(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'requested', 'request_state': self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0].generic_request_id.state })
    return True
```

This way I solved my problem.
I'll leave this here, hoping this will help someone in the future!